# How to use css to remove a blue highlight from button

Tags: button, click, highlight

Please check the screenshot below. I basically want to remove the blue highlight that's added to my button when active click is activated. I would like to remove this effect as well from my input text box. To keep it from showing up when I'm clicked on it.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of CSS properties which your web browser will set as part of its default button style, these are border and outline.

to remove any border and outline simply use;

```
border: none;
outline: none;
```

These styles can be applied to a specific element however it might be worth looking into [CSS resets](http://cssreset.com/), these are chucks of CSS which reset all elements ready for your own styles, helping prevent issues like this where a browsers default style gets in the way.

Answer (score 0):

In the part where you style your botton (css), try typing in: `text-decoration:none;`